# Equivalent Curl Call for this html form

Tags: curl

I have the following html form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://api.website.com/upload/index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="myhandle" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

What is the equivalent CURL call if I were in Bash on linux?  I tried :

```
curl -X POST '-F file=@1.jpg -d myhandle=helloworld' http://api.website.com/upload/index.php
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
curl: (26) failed creating formpost data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
curl --form file=@1.jpg --form myhandle=helloworld http://api.website.com/upload/index.php
```